# update old node.js to new version doesn't work

Tags: node.js

My linux system used to install a old version node.js environment 0.8.14, now updated it to latest node.js through this

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

when update is done and i rebooted the linux system, then I found it is still the old version node.js.

Comment: You could always remove the package and install the binaries directly.  That's the method I usually use... it's painless.  http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/08/07/node-v0-8-6-stable/  http://nodejs.org/download/

Comment: Your link is to an old version of node (and one with notable security flaws)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm willing to bet you installed the previous version through `apt-get` without first adding Chris Lea's PPA.  The standard Ubuntu repositories have an old version of node.

You'll need to uninstall this old version before you can get the new one:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove nodejs # Remove the package itself
sudo apt-get autoremove # Remove any unneeded dependencies
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Comment: I have nodejs installed, it is the latest version, but when I typed npm -v, it showed me: /usr/local/bin/npm, /usr/local/bin/node: bad interpreter, no such file or directory.  it is strange, it should include npm , isn't it

Comment: That looks like an entirely different problem than the one you've posted.  Yes, my method should also install npm.  Perhaps ask this in a new question.

Comment: Works for me!
I tried http://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs but same version even after reboot! Thx!