# npm ERR! failed to fetch on ubuntu

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to get node, express, and mongo installed on a Lenovo u430 with a Intel® Core™ i5-4258U CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4 and running Ubuntu 13.10.  I'm trying to use [this guide](http://qugstart.com/blog/node-js/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-and-create-an-app-in-5-minutes/comment-page-1/).

When I get to the step to run (with sudo)

```
npm install -g express
```

I get the following error:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-3.4.4.tgz
npm ERR! failed to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-3.4.4.tgz

npm ERR! Error: SSL Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/main.js:356:28)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.ondata (http.js:1150:24)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream._push (tls.js:375:27)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.cycle (tls.js:734:20)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.write (tls.js:130:13)
npm ERR!     at Socket.ondata (stream.js:38:26)
npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-20-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "express"
npm ERR! cwd /usr/local/src/npm
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.11
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.1
npm ERR! message SSL Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /usr/local/src/npm/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

I noticed the error msg is telling me I have node -v v0.6.11, but when I run 
    node -v
from the cl it doesn't return anything.  However if I run 
    nodejs -v
from the command line I get
    v0.10.28
I've done a few hours of searching for this and haven't been able to find any solutions/workarounds.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy`, that will install a symlink so that `node` will point to `nodejs`. Are you using an http/https proxy?

Comment: I tried `sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy` and but it did not install.  Got `dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs-legacy_0.10.15~dfsg1-4_all.deb (--unpack):`.  I'm not using a proxy (that I'm aware of), I'm a relative Linux noob though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [update old node.js to new version doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034191/update-old-node-js-to-new-version-doesnt-work)